# Nav button highlight works in desktop browser, but not in android mobile browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, nav

Alright so I'm using **jQueryMobile, jQuery/JavaScript** and **CSS** to make a navigation bar that allows you to select an option from the top UL tree (horizontal nav bar) and then also select an option from the resulting submenu while the option from the parent ul tree is still highlighted.

This works in a desktop browser and **in this jsfiddle I just created (at the bottom)**; however, **once I'm in a mobile browser (Android Internet or Chrome Mobile)**, the parent ul no longer stays highlighted.

Why?

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">


    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <nav id="navbar" data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a class="ui-btn-active" href="#">Real-Time</a>
                    <ul class="secondLvl">
                        <li><a href="#">Choice 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Choice 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Choice 3</a></li>
                        <li class="lastNav"><a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="pageChange">Database Functions</a>
                    <ul class="secondLvl">
                        <li><a href="#">Another Choice 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another Choice 2</a></li>
                        <li class="lastNav"><a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="pageChange">Settings/Configuration</a>
                    <ul class="secondLvl">
                        <li><a href="login.php">Logout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">A Third Choice 3</a></li>
                        <li class="lastNav"><a></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

    </div>

    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>
            Home
        </h1>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#home
{
    background-color: #5f6975;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#navbar > ul {
    position: relative;
}

#navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    background: #5f6975; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 1000px;
}

#navbar ul ul li {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui-navbar li:last-child .ui-btn {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
}

.lastNav a {
    height: 100vh;
    pointer-events: none;
}
        #navbar ul ul li a.active {
            background: #4b545f;
        }

    #navbar ul ul ul {
        position: absolute; 
        left: 100%; 
        top: 0;
    }

#navbar ul li.active > ul { 
            display: block;
}

#navbar ul li { 
    float: left;
}

    #navbar ul li.active {
        background: #4b545f;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
    }

#navbar ul li a {
    display:block; 
    padding: 25px 40px; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

JavaScript/JQuery:

```
//Clear Text Fields
$(document).on("pagehide", function (e){
    $(e.target).remove();
});

//Setup Side Navbar
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#home", function(){
    var navItems = $("#navbar > ul > li");
    var subWidth = 100 / navItems.length;

    $("#navbar > ul > li").each(function( index ) {
        $(this).find("ul").each(function(i) {
            var top = (i + 1) * 100;
            $(this).css({"position": "absolute", 
                         "width": subWidth + "%",
                         "top": top + "%"}); 
        });
    });
});

//Make Side Navbar stick
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#home', function(event){
    $('#navbar ul li').on('click', function () {

        //removing the previous selected menu state
        $('#navbar ul li.active').removeClass('active');

        //is this element from the second level menu?
        if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('secondLvl'))
        {
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
        } //end if

        //otherwise just highlight the element
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } //end else
    })  

    $('ul').find('a').on('click', function() {

        $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('ui-btn-active');

        if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('secondLvl'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        }
    })
})
```

Here's my **JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/LLx7vgjo/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using vclick event instead click. The jQuery Mobile "vclick" event handler simulates the "onclick" event handler on mobile devices. I hope this helps!